# OpenAI Gym + WSL2 + VcXsrv moving window issue

Tags: python, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

The most common way to run OpenAI Gym on Windows seems to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux and an X Server like VcXsrv or XMing.
I managed to get it all up and running, but I have an annoying issue in which the video output to VcXsrv (or XMing, I tried that too) gets offset inside the window if it's moved around, like this:

[image: Before moving]
[image: After moving]

This is pretty annoying for bigger environments that maybe end up behind other windows on the desktop and such. I found that if you setup "One Large Window" or "Fullscreen" in the X Server the problem of moving rendered part doesn't happen, but it seems like a suboptimal solution.

The settings I have for VcXsrv are:

- Multiple Windows
- Start no Client
- Extra settings all checked

While I export the following env variables on WSL2:

```
export DISPLAY="`grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | sed 's/nameserver //'`:0"
export "LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1"
```

Has anyone had the same issue or figured how to solve it? For reference, other applications through the X Server render normally and can be moved around without issue.

Comment: How did you manage to make XMing work? Could you share your steps? I am struggling since 2 days to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, and now it's gone. I guess unchecking `Native opengl` was the key step.

Here are my configurations.

[image: Display settings]
[image: Client startup]
[image: Extra settings]